# How do I compare user roles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a ban command with discord.js, but I don't know how to check if the target is a lower role than the user executing the command. I tried looking it up, but I couldn't find it. I've seen this function in other discord bots, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GuildMember has [`.highestRole`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=highestRole) that returns the top role the member has. From there you can compare the position of both members highest roles and determine if one can ban each other. You can even use [`.comparePositionTo()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo) to compare the roles.

```
if(message.member.highestRole.comparePositionTo(message.mentions.members.first().highestRole) > 0){
    //member has higher role then first mentioned member
    message.mentions.members.first().ban();
}
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Let me know if that thing doesn't work, i can try fix it if it doesn't

Comment: `first` is a function, there it should be `message.mentions.members.first().highestRole` and `message.mentions.members.first().ban()`

Comment: Oh you probably had a pending edit for my answer. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

in v.14, one should use:

`...member.roles.highest`

My current working code (though, based on reaction):

```
if(reaction.message.member.roles.highest.comparePositionTo(reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(botID).roles.highest) >= 0)
    {
     console.log('They tried to affect equal or higher role!');
     return;
    }
```

Compared role inside brackets is:

= 0 - equal

> 0 - higher

< 0 - lower

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing a full example of the solution and how it helps the OP.